# "Become customer" button on my website requires the POST customer endpoint to be public. I don't want it public. How do I get around this?

Tags: python, rest, flask, jwt, flask-jwt

I have a web app communicating with a backend through a couple of REST endpoints.

I also have a home page where people can become customers to the above mentioned web app.

All the web app's endpoints requires authentication (a logged in user) to be called (JWT tokens) but on my home page I have a "Become customer" button which makes a `POST /customers` request, which I have to leave public (But I don't want anyone to be able to spam my endpoint with new customers.

What is the standard way of getting around this problem?

I'm using Python, Flask and Flask-JWT in my backend.

Comment: CAPTCHAs and rate limiting are typical defenses against DOS attacks.

Comment: You can't. Do you honestly think that major services (Facebook, Twitter, Instagram...) have no fake users that have been automatically created by spamming the register button? You could add a reCaptcha or similar to mitigate it, but there's a chance you'll not be able to completely stop it.

Answer (score 0):

The only option would be a user role that is added, for a limited amount of time (30mins). If the user has this role, then they have permission to view it.

Make sense?